# EL vhost en apache instalado en ubuntu 18 virtualizado no funciona

Tags: windows, ubuntu, apache2

Estoy usuando windows 10 como sistema operativo físico, y he instalado virtualbox para virtualizar ubunto 18 e instalar apache2, al igual configurar el vhost. Lo hice todo pero no funciona, cuando coloco la ip del servidor ubuntu al navegador de windows 10 me envia en automatico a la carpeta que decide que me redireccionara. Configure el /etc/hosts y coloque 
       `192.168.0.12 sistema.com.devel` pero no me direcciona a la carpeta o no sé si necesito instalar Bind9 para eso. Espero encontrar la respuesta con su ayuda, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder acceder de manera sencilla a tu servidor ubuntu en virtualbox debes asegurarte de que la configuración de red esta en "modo puente", de esta manera le dices a la maquina virtual que se situe como nodo en la misma red.

Comment: Ya estaba configurado en bridge mode. Creo que necesito instalar el DNS para poder visualizar en mi maquina fisica.

Comment: No es necesario, ya probaste si puedes alcanzar maquina virtual con un ping?

Comment: Hago ping y todo perfecto, pero no con el nombre del host.

Comment: La dirección IP: `192.168.0.12 sistema.com.devel` lo pusiste en Ubuntu o en Windows?

Comment: El ping lo hago desde windows a ubuntu

Comment: Si el ping funciona entonces bastaría con que configures el archivo ets/hosts en windows.